# One script for several views in a templated custom list

Tags: list-view, list-template, cewp, script

I have a custom list (MOSS/SharePoint 2007), and several views (around 7).
Now I would like to know if it's possible to apply a script through a CEWP for all the views, without add a webpart, select a CEWP, link my script file etc.

Repeat it for all my views (7 times) is so boring and "ugly". I want a portable and generic method, allowing me to apply this script to all my views, and once my list is templated, the script will still be "linked" to my list and all my views.

Is it possible? Or should I keep doing it manually?

Comment: Hello @Funnycuni. Nice Question, But i don't think it's possible. You are asking to embed a JavaScript in definition of a list which is not feasible. If i will get any workaround, i will update you.

Comment: @VarunVerma, so I have to create 7 Content Editor Web Part (CEWP), for each views, and link my JavaScript file to them manually. I'm okay with it, but I'm wondering if all the CEWP will be "saved" when my list will be templated, or if I will have to re-create them in future deployment on other site?

Comment: No. Nothing will get save in template :) CEWP is a control to page and not list :). yes you need to redo it

Comment: Even if I export the CEWP and save it in the Web Part Gallerie?

Comment: Then it will be ok. But again you need to add that exported webpart to each and every page :)